# Value In alert Dialogue is not updating and alert dialogue is not closing Flutter

Tags: flutter, alert

I'm new to Flutter, I'm building an application which requires an alert dialogue which contains a value, the value gets updated after each second. But In my case value is not updating even alert dialogue is not closing by itself.

```
  Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
  BuildContext dialoguecontext;
      if ((stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds / 6000) >= 1) {
        stopwatch.stop();
        assetsAudioPlayer.stop();

          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              dialoguecontext = context;
              return Dialog(
                child:
                new Text('Break Time Left : ${breakTime} s'),
              );
            },
          );

        while(breakTime > 0)
          {
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

            setState(() {
              breakTime--;
            });
          }
          breakTime = 40;
        Navigator.pop(dialoguecontext);
        ++imgnumber;
        assetsAudioPlayer.next();
        stopwatch.start();
      }
    });
```

How to make this code work properly?

Answer (score 0):

In [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) you can not change any value.

Following line are from official documents.

> The widget returned by the builder does not share a context with the
>   location that showDialog is originally called from. **Use a
>   StatefulBuilder or a custom StatefulWidget if the dialog needs to
>   update dynamically.**

So, you have to use Stateful widget.

Following minimal code help you to understand more.

```
class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  int t = 10;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Press"),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) {
                  return NewWidget(t);
                });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int t;
  NewWidget(this.t);
  @override
  _NewWidgetState createState() => _NewWidgetState();
}

class _NewWidgetState extends State<NewWidget> {
  int newt;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    newt = widget.t;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text(newt.toString()),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            newt = newt + 1;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your whole dialog is in stateful widget, which is fine but build  of showDialog is required to be in different scaffold.

Comment: I need to update value without a button, the example you have posted contains a button.

Comment: i just demonstrated that changing value is possible that way, now you can use your time and change value.